# Failed to resolve Ksoap2

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-ksoap2

I have a problem with Android Studio saying:

> failed to resolve
>   com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.papiroomdemo.webservicetest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        repositories {
            maven { url 'http://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo' }

        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.0.0'
}
```

> Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1 Show in File
> Show in Project Structure
>   dialog

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your url in `repositories` section is invalid. You should add 
`https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/`:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}
```

More info here: http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

/// add these lines in module gradle

```
allprojects {
            repositories {
               google()
               jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/'
           }
     }
}
```